# Probability of both M and N consecutive head runs in K independent tails terminated coin toss runs

Tags: probability, distributions, statistical-significance, randomness, probabilistic-programming

Let's say I repeatedly toss a coin each day, until I get tails which terminates each run. I do that 1999 times (1999 runs). I count how many heads I got each run. 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 5, 0 etc.

What is the probability I get both a run of 20 heads in a row, as well as a run of 18 heads on any given day? M = 20 N = 18 K = 1999

The system I'm developing called RANDEVU essentially does that, flips coins each day. And I got a run of 20, 18, and 2 runs of 11 today (out of 1999 runs). That seems kinda unlikely.

I would expect to see slightly less than 1 run of 11 heads each day (assuming I do 1999 runs). So... I'm not really surprised by 2x11, but the 18 and 20 - on the same day. I find that sus.

I did some simulations and it seems like each day has about 1 / 2^18 (within an order of magnitude) chance to have a run of 18 heads as well as a run of 20 heads.
Which is 0.00038147%. In other words, that happens about once in 700ish years... and I got it on like the 5th day since I started flipping them coins. Note: coin tosses are just an analogy to simplify things. If you would like some more insight into the system, check the twitter link below, there is also a Github link there. https://twitter.com/randevurdv

Am I really just this lucky or am I missing something? And if I am just lucky, how lucky am I exactly?

Can anyone help? :)